# background size não funciona

Tags: html5, css3, imagem

Quero colocar uma imagem como backgroud de uma div,porém a imagem não se adequa a div mesmo eu colocando o background-size: cover.

**Css**

```
.jogo_destaque {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%),
    url('../images/capa\ horizon\ forbiden\ west.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**Html**

```
<main>
      <div class="jogo_destaque">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="titulo_jogo">Horizon Forbidden West</h3>
          <p class="descricao">
            O mundo aberto de Horizon Forbidden West é um grande parque de diversões para os gamers. 
            Um mundo expansivo cheio de perigo e aventura – e Aloy precisará de muitas ferramentas, armas e habilidades para sobreviver ao que seus inimigos jogarão nela. 
            Neste novo trailer, saiba mais como a Aloy pode evoluir e criar estratégias em um mundo cada vez mais ameaçador.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
```

Resolução da foto que quero colocar como background:1024 x 1024
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No caso você quer colocar a imagem para ocupar toda a tela ou somente não quer que ela se repita?

Comment: ocupar toda a div

Comment: Acabei de alterar a foto, tinha enviado errado

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que utilizar o `object-fit` dá uma olhada na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: Segundo a documentação o cover preenche toda a div com a imagem, a imagem até ocupa toda a div mas não se adequa a ela.Como eu faço pra imagem não ficar cortada?

Comment: Remove essa linha `height: 400px;`

Comment: Já tinha feito isso antes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no tamanho de sua imagem com a `div`, neste caso você tem duas opções:

1. Aumentar o tamanho da sua `div` par ao tamanho da imagem:

```
.jogo_destaque {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%),
    url('../images/capa\ horizon\ forbiden\ west.jpg');
  height: 1024px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

2. Ajustar o `background-size` para 100% do tamanho da sua `div`, mas tenha em mente que pode haver uma distorção na imagem:

```
.jogo_destaque {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%),
    url('../images/capa\ horizon\ forbiden\ west.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```